# Join characters from list of strings by index

Tags: python

For example, I have the following **list.**

```
list=['abc', 'def','ghi','jkl','mn']
```

I want to make a **new list** as:

```
newList=['adgjm','behkn','cfil']
```

picking every *first character* of *each element* forming a new string then appending into the new list, and then with the *second character* of *every element* and so on:

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is zipping the strings in the list, which will interleave the characters from each string in the specified fashion, and join them back with `str.join`:

```
l = ['abc', 'def','ghi','jkl']

list(map(''.join, zip(*l)))
# ['adgj', 'behk', 'cfil']
```

---

For strings with different length, use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), and fill with an empty string:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
l = ['abcZ', 'def','ghi','jkl']

list(map(''.join, zip_longest(*l, fillvalue='')))
# ['adgj', 'behk', 'cfil', 'Z']
```

Comment: IIRC `map` is not really considered pythonic.  It's a very simple and readable answer though.

Comment: @yatu I agree.  I'm not adverse in using `map` myself, just saying some might not consider `map` pythonic to the first comment.

Comment: @c4f4t0r It's a noteworthy distinction, but Python 2 is already sunsetted in 2020, so the relevant conversation *should be* for Python 3 unless version is specifically mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
>>> list1 =['abc', 'def','ghi','jkl']
>>> newlist = []
>>> for args in zip(*list1):
...     newlist.append(''.join(args))
... 
>>> newlist
['adgj', 'behk', 'cfil']
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
>>> newlist = [''.join(args) for args in zip(*list1)]
>>> newlist
['adgj', 'behk', 'cfil']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list=['abc', 'def','ghi','jkl']
n = len(list[0])
newList = []
i = 0
for i in range(n):
    newword = ''
    for word in list:
        newword += word[i]
    newList.append(newword)

print(newList)
```